# name 'split' is not defined issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have this code snippet that do some basic calculation on two text files. 
My code:

```
with open('one.txt', 'r') as one, open('two.txt', 'r') as two:
    next(two) # skip first line in two.txt
    for line_one, line_two in zip(one, two):
        one_a = int(split(line_one, ",")[0])
        two_b = int(split(line_two, " ")[1])
        print(one_a - two_b)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    one_a = split(line_one, ",")[0]
NameError: name 'split' is not defined
```

I have no idea why, help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what about `one_a = int(line_one.split(","))[0])` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` function can't be used like this, 
you should use `"some string".split(' ');`

so your code should be

```
one_a = int((line_one.split(",")[0])
two_b = int(line_two.split(" ")[1])
```

Comment: as the error states there is some issues with your indentation. what you can do is after the colon(`:`) in the for loop line. press enter, which will create a new line with some indentation. put your code there.

Comment: deleted comment , huh? @E.W

Comment: Yeah, deleted comment. I solved it. Thanks for your help sir!